# SolrClient not committing changes until restart of solr process

Tags: python, solr, client, commit, restart

I am having some trouble getting [SolrClient](https://github.com/moonlitesolutions/SolrClient) to immediately reflect changes I am making. If I write to the index, I need to first restart the solr process I have running, and only then can I see the changes I am writing. Here is the code I am using

```
import json
from SolrClient import SolrClient


def read_all():

    client = SolrClient('http://localhost:8983/solr')

    res = client.query('test', {
        'q' : '*:*'
    })

    res = json.loads(res.get_json())
    docs = res['response']['docs']

    for doc in docs:
        print (doc)


def index_json():

    client = SolrClient('http://localhost:8983/solr')

    docs = [
        {'id' : '8', 'field8' : 'value8'},
    ]

    client.index_json('test', json.dumps(docs))

    client.commit('test')
```

So, pretend I have fields 1-7 already indexed, and then I run my **read_all** function. I will see docs 1-7 printed out. Then I run **index_json** to index doc 8. If I immediated run **read_all** again, I will only see 1-7 printed out. I need to run solr stop, and then solr start. Only then will I see docs 1-8 printed out.

I read on a similar sounding post that I needed to commit my changes, which is why I added

```
client.commit('test')
```

at the bottom, but it doesn't seem to be working. Help please?

Comment: Can you see the commit request in the Solr log? As well - try adding `openSearcher=True` to the commit call, so that your client will wait until the committed data is actually searchable.

Answer (score 0):

The commit function of the library sets the parameters as follows:

```
openSearcher=False
softCommit=False
waitSearcher=True
commit=True
```

Since its a hard commit and openSearch is false, caches are not invalidated and hence you cannot see new added records. You can refer [here](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/08/23/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/) and [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig).

So you can decide according to the use case the type of commit you want and set them accordingly. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I'll check after work and then give you the accept if this ends up working.